# Node recognised in Command/Power shell but not in powershell of VSCode

Tags: node.js, windows, powershell

My Node and NPM installation on a windows 10 machine is recognized in Command shell and Powershell, but not in the default Powershell of my VSCode. If I open an additional powershell, it's recognized.

node -v returns the following error". Exact same error for "npm" with "node" replaced as "npm"

```
node: The term 'node' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the  is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ node -v
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (node:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Downloaded location: LTS version from https://nodejs.org/en/download/
Have added C:\Program Files\nodejs in the path of Environment Variables.

Comment: "Have added C:\Program Files\nodejs in the path of Environment Variables." - are you sure it's not located in `C:\Program Files\nodejs\bin`?

Comment: No. The node executable is in C:\Program Files\nodejs. No bin folder there. Further conducted a full scan of my PC for any other alternative node installation. Found none.